# Replace JSON objects in unknown positions inside a JSON tree

Tags: json, jq, edit, hierarchical-data

In a JSON file I need to replace encrypted values with their clear text values as an initialization process using the command line tool `jq`. An application will then re-encrypt the values with its own keys, overwriting the clear text values. Encrypted values are represented as "$crypto" objects, containing information about the encryption method and which keys were used, looking like this:

```
{
    "$crypto" : {
        "type" : "x-simple-encryption",
        "value" : {
            "cipher" : "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding",
            "stableId" : "someId",
            "salt" : "4J5ckE6+JaS8TLqAN4073g==",
            "data" : "vBeHAPJXLl+X/8Enp9vxMA==",
            "keySize" : 16,
            "purpose" : "someDescription",
            "iv" : "N2xCe5RiJibHv9hLY+OduA==",
            "mac" : "VoOo1BKptwfqIJeSOb/qGA=="
        }
    }
}
```

These "$crypto" objects can be anywhere in the JSON structure. A sample input document looks like this:

```
{
    "unknownKey1" : {
        "unknownKey2" : {
            "name" : "JWT_SESSION",
            "properties" : {
                "maxTokenLifeMinutes" : 120,
                "tokenIdleTimeMinutes" : 30
            }
        },
        "unknownKey3" : [
            {
                "unknownKey4" : "STATIC_USER",
                "unknownKey5" : {
                    "unknownKey6" : "internal/user",
                    "unknownKey7" : "anonymous",
                    "unknownKey8" : {
                        "$crypto" : {
                            "type" : "x-simple-encryption",
                            "value" : {
                                "cipher" : "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding",
                                "stableId" : "someId",
                                "salt" : "4J5ckE6+JaS8TLqAN4073g==",
                                "data" : "vBeHAPJXLl+X/8Enp9vxMA==",
                                "keySize" : 16,
                                "purpose" : "someDescription",
                                "iv" : "N2xCe5RiJibHv9hLY+OduA==",
                                "mac" : "VoOo1BKptwfqIJeSOb/qGA=="
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "enabled" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So the value of "unknownKey8" was encrypted. I need that document to look like this:

```
{
    "unknownKey1" : {
        "unknownKey2" : {
            "name" : "JWT_SESSION",
            "properties" : {
                "maxTokenLifeMinutes" : 120,
                "tokenIdleTimeMinutes" : 30
            }
        },
        "unknownKey3" : [
            {
                "unknownKey4" : "STATIC_USER",
                "unknownKey5" : {
                    "unknownKey6" : "internal/user",
                    "unknownKey7" : "anonymous",
                    "unknownKey8" : "clearTextValue"
                },
                "enabled" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have been able to find crypto objects in the input file using the following command:

```
cat input.json | jq 'paths | select(.[-1] == "$crypto")'
[
  "unknownKey1",
  "unknownKey3",
  0,
  "unknownKey5",
  "unknownKey8",
  "$crypto"
]
```

But I have not been able to make meaningful progress on performing the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following performs the replacement described in the text.  An invocation along the lines of

```
jq --arg cleartext "clearTextValue" -f decrypt.jq sample.json
```

is assumed.  If your jq does not have `walk/1`, then either upgrade to jq 1.6 or include its def before its invocation (google search terms: `jq def walk builtin.jq`).

```
# input is assumed to be an object
def decrypt($value):
  with_entries(if .value|type == "object"
    then with_entries(if .value | (type == "object" and has("$crypto"))
      then .value = $value else . end)
    else . end) ;

walk(if type == "object" then decrypt($cleartext) else . end)
```

Comment: Holy cow, @peak, what a nice solution! It took me a while to validate, as my jq version was 1.5, which did not have the "walk" method, but an upgrade to 1.6 fixed that. Thank you very much for taking the time! 

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the accepted answer and if using jq v1.5, use this as `decrypt.jq`

```
# input is assumed to be an object
def decrypt($value):
  with_entries(if .value|type == "object"
    then with_entries(if .value | (type == "object" and has("$crypto"))
      then .value = $value else . end)
    else . end) ;

# walk was added after the release of jq@1.5
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

walk(if type == "object" then decrypt($cleartext) else . end)
```